# Running document.referrer from iframe context does not return full URL in Safari 12

Tags: javascript

I have not seen this before and can't really find any solid information about it, but I am running some code from within an iframe on the page and the `document.referrer` property is not returning the full URL.

So for example in Chrome and other browsers, I am seeing:
`http://www.test.com/thisurl`

...but Safari is **only** returning the hostname, so just returns:
`http://www.test.com/`

I don't see why this shouldn't return the full URL when getting it from within an iframe on the page...I am seeing this with both http and https protocols (iframe being the same as the outside page).

It should always be equal to the `window.parent.location.href` shouldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This must be WebKit's new privacy policy enabled in new versions of Safari. The official announcement is here: https://webkit.org/blog/8311/intelligent-tracking-prevention-2-0/ down in the section "Origin-Only Referrer for Domains Without User Interaction". So basically only the origin part of the referrer (`window.parent.location.origin`) is being sent in the response.

Beware also that the referrer you're seeing in other browsers is not the full `location.href` of the parent window. If there is a hash in the URL, as in `http://www.test.com/thisurl#yourhashhere`, it will not appear in the referrer.